# Let $\ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{Z}\ \cup [-1,1]).\ $ Does the set $\{\lfloor{x^k}\rfloor:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ have roughly as many evens as odds?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, number-theory, probability-theory, real-numbers

I couldn't fit the precise question in the title, but I tried. What I mean precisely is:

> Let $\ x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus(\ \mathbb{Z}\ \cup [-1,1]\ ).\ $
> Furthermore, for each $\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ define $\ A_n = \{\
>  \lfloor{x^k}\rfloor:\ k\in\mathbb{N}\ \text{and}\ k\leq n\ \}\ $ where $\ \lfloor{\cdot}\rfloor\ $ is the floor function.
> Proposition:
>
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\text{amount of odd integers in}\
>  A_n}{\text{amount of integers in}\ A_n} = \frac{1}{2}\quad $$

It is simply the apparently chaotic nature of the sets that makes me think this. And I know nothing of Chaos theory, so it's possible I'm out of my depth here. But I don't know if this has anything to do with Chaos theory, so I don't think I'm out of place for asking this question.

Is this known to be true for some numbers $\ x\ $ and known to be false for others?

Is it even known whether or not the limit always converges?

Perhaps this can even be proven via a probabilistic approach? The arising sets seem to be chaotic in nature, so perhaps something to do with Chaos/Ergodic theory? Or perhaps there is a much more elementary approach? I've no idea...

Edit: The responses thus far make me think that for radical numbers $\ x,\ $ the limit will $\ \neq\frac{1}{2}.\ $ And some algebraic numbers may give rise to patterns. So transcendental numbers are "more interesting/more chaotic/random." But I am not sure of any this, and I know little about the properties of transcendental numbers.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: That question makes me believe I'm missing something relatively elementary. Interesting.

Comment: It was not my intention to suggest that. There are simply many viable approaches by fairly elementary methods, that I suspect you are familiar with, based on your previous question. You could at least share your findings after trying some approaches, instead of just posing a question and adding a few blurbs without any real thought to them.

Comment: Also, more context would improve the question. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: For starters, what happens with $x=\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Someone asked me "where did that problem come from?" on another question a while ago, and I didn't have a great answer other than, "I'm interested in maths and I often ponder things that I don't know about because I find maths interesting...". I guess I'm currently delving into some sort of mixture of real analysis and number theory. What happens with $x=\sqrt{2}\ ?$ Ok so Maybe $ \frac{3}{4}\ $ of the numbers are even? Obviously at least $\frac{1}{2}\ $ the numbers are even, but this is all I can say for sure...

Comment: Fair enough to the origin of the problem. But I suggest again that you give the question some thought before dumping it here. Good ideas can take time and effort to find and flesh out. A few evenings of trials and error, some research, a few nights of pondering. Also, sharing your attempts gives other users here an idea of what level to answer the question at.

Answer (score 1):

Questions involving floors of powers of a given number always invite solutions involving Pisot–Vijayaraghavan numbers. I will show how to make all the numbers in $A$ odd. Let $x_1=x$ be a quadratic irrational and $x_2$ be its algebraic conjugate, and $\sigma_1=x_1+x_2$ and $\sigma_2=x_1x_2$. We have that

$$x_1^{n+1}+x_2^{n+1}=\sigma_1(x_1^n+x_2^n)-\sigma_2(x_1^{n-1}+x_2^{n-1}).$$

So if we think of this as a recursive sequence $k_n=x_1^n+x_2^n$, $k_1=\sigma_1$, $k_2=\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_2$ we can make it always even by choosing $\sigma_1$ even, and then if $0<x_2<1$ we have that $x_1^n=k_n-x_2^n$, that is $x_1^n$ is an even number minus some small positive quantity, so its floor is odd. With a bit of trial and error that can be achieved with $\sigma_1=6$, $\sigma_2=3$, so $x_1=3+\sqrt 6$ and $x_2=3-\sqrt 6$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this known to be true for some numbers $x$ and known to be false
> for others?

For $x = \varphi^2 = \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, the integers $\lfloor x^n \rfloor$ (with $n > 0$) are precisely the even-indexed Lucas numbers minus one.  These repeat in the pattern even, even, odd, so the limit is $\frac{1}{3}$.  If $x = \varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ instead, then $\lfloor x^n \rfloor$ alternates between $L_n$ and $L_n - 1$, so the repeating pattern is odd, even, even, even, odd, odd; and the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ in this case.

I will leave the harder questions (whether the limit always exists, and whether it equals $\frac{1}{2}$ for $100\%$ of choices of $x$) to others.

Comment: I have not heard of the Lucas numbers before, so thanks for this.